# Ubuntu - Steam downloads corrupted files and the game redownload. Never ending cycle

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, ubuntu

I'm trying to download Counter-Strike GO on my Ubuntu 16.04 system and by the end of game download, Steam says that there are corrupted files and if I click on the play button, it starts re-downloading. I don't know what I should do.

Can you help me?

Comment: Check your game folder before you start the game... are the game files there? Do you have file access? Does Steam have enough permissions to actually download everything correctly?